# Get value of java options in jruby

Tags: jruby

I'd like to know, in a running jruby script, which java options are set. Is there a way to do this?

My problem is this: There are some scripts that I know require much more memory than others, and I would like to add a constraint in the code so that execution will stop early with proper warnings, rather than running out of memory at some unspecified time in the future.

Perhaps something I could stick in a BEGIN{}, like:

```
if is_set_joption?('-J-Xmx') then
    if get_joption('-J-Xmx').match(/\d+/)[0].to_i < 1000 then
        puts "You're gonna run out of memory...";
        abort();
    end
else
    puts "I recommend you start with -J-Xmx1000m.";
    abort();
end
```

(... where `is_set_joption?` and `get_joption` are made up methods.)

Running jruby 1.7.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do:

```
require 'java';
java_import 'java.lang.Runtime';
mxm = Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory.to_i;

if mxm < (512 * 1024 * 1024) then
  raise "You're gonna need a bigger boat.";
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be in your ENV if you've set JAVA_OPTS in your environment.  You could get it from that..  You've already initiated the JVM at this point though, so you'll want to set that elsewhere, like in your command line when you exec jruby with -D

Comment: In this case the java options are all passed as commandline `-J-something` arguments.